# How to add a specific string in a row

Tags: string, perl

I have following legacy code:

```
  open(FILE_Errors,">Errors.txt") || die "Error at >";     
  undef(@arrayrow);                  

  open(File_To_Read,"<$file") || die "File not Found";
  while($row=<File_To_Read>) {
    push(@arrayrow,$row);
  }
  close(File_To_Read);

  foreach(@arrayrow) {
    if($_=~ m/errorcode: 230/i) {       
        print FILE_Errors "$_";
    } elsif($_=~ m/errors/i) {
        print FILE_Errors "$_";
    }
  }
}
close (file);
```

This code loads files and searches for rows containing `errorcode: 230` or `errors` - this works fine. It prints the found lines into an Errors.txt - which also works perfect.

this would transform  something like:

File A.txt:

```
lorem ipsum errorcode: 230
loem ipsum
```

File B.txt:

```
lorem ipsum
loem errors ipsum
```

Errors.txt:
    lorem ipsum errorcode: 230
    loem errors ipsum

Now it should append from which file the lines are.
Errors.txt:

```
lorem ipsum errorcode: 230 A.txt
loem errors ipsum B.txt
```

What I've tried and the related outputs (which not make sense to me):
Where line equals `lorem ipsum errorcode ..`

```
print FILE_Errors "$file $_" # produces:
A.txt line
 A.txt line
 A.txt line
 B.txt line
 B.txt line
```

And

```
print FILE_Errors "$_ $file" # produces:
line
 A.txtline
 A.txtline
 A.txtline
 B.txtline
 B.txt
```

How have I to arrange the variables to get:

```
line A.txt
line B.txt
```

PS: i've read the [Perl for Java introduction](http://kevinboone.net/javaperl.html)

edit1:@Jonathan Leffler

```
chomp;
print FILE_Errors "$_ $file\n";
#will produce:
A.txt line
A.txt line
A.txt line
B.txt line
B.txt line
```

By changing the statement to: "$file $_\n" it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chomp` to remove the trailing newline, then add the file name and newline in the printing:

```
chomp;
print FILE_Errors "$_ $file\n";
```

---

Note that in your script, `close(file);` doesn't close either of the files that were opened (but that line and the brace just before it are interlopers in the script extract; the question doesn't show the balancing open brace). Also, unless there is more processing on the array than is shown, there was no need to slurp the whole file into memory; you could process one line at a time.  And if you do need all the data in memory at once, you can reduce the entire `while` loop to just:

```
@arrayrow = <File_to_Read>;
```

Comment: Thank you! - i'm really impressed about this @arrayrow = <File_to_Read>; possiblity!

Comment: @MemLeak If you like that, you should be aware that all Perl code has such possibilities, if you keep in mind to consider list context vs scalar context. The file handle readline() function is an iterator in scalar context (e.g. `my $line = <$fh>`), but in list context it is exhausted all at once, such as when using an array `@array = <$fh>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script can largely be replaced by Perl built-in functionality, and can be done as simply as:

```
perl -nlwe'/error(?:s|code: 230)/i and print' input1 input2 ... > errors.txt
```

You can also place this in a source file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    /error(?:s|code: 230)/i and print;
}
```

If you want, you can hard code the paths, or make them optional:

```
my $error_output = shift || "errors.txt";
open my $outfh, ">", $error_output or die "Cannot open $error_output: $!";
```

Though personally, I would prefer to type my own paths, as it is less likely to surprise you.

Note that the regex is the combined version of your two regexes. Also, note that you should use three argument `open` with explicit mode `">"`, lexical file handle (instead of global) and an explicit error checking, using the `$!` error to display what went wrong.